# C++ no match for ‘operator+=’ (operand types are ‘float’ and ‘std::chrono::duration<long int>’)

Tags: c++, c++11, time

Estoy tratando de calcular el tiempo promedio de ejecución de un programa, para 10 ejecuciones, para ello uso la librería `chrono` de C++11, no obstante, me está saliendo un error que dice que no hay un operador para hacer el `+=`, tengo entendido que variables declaradas como `auto` se puede igualar con otros tipos de datos.

Código:

```
int i=0;
float execution_time=0;
while(i<10){
   auto start = chrono::system_clock::now();


   coche_.A_star(map_);//para llamar a A_star,asi se implementan constructores


   auto end = chrono::system_clock::now();

   auto elapsed = chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::seconds>(end - start);

   execution_time += elapsed; //ERROR
   i++;
}

cout << "tiempo de ejecucion" << execution_time/10 <<endl;
```

Error:

```
error: no match for ‘operator+=’ (operand types are ‘float’ and ‘std::chrono::duration<long int>’)
                     execution_time += elapsed;
```

El código forma parte de una función más grande, solo pongo lo relevante para entender la duda. He declarando `using namespace std`.

Se agradece ayuda, gracias.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Tengo entendido que variables declaradas como `auto` se puede igualar con otros tipos de datos.

Pues entendiste mal. La característica que describes es común en los lenguajes de tipado débil, pero C++ no es uno de ellos.

C++ es un lenguaje de [tipado fuerte](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tipado_fuerte), esto implica que las variables tienen un solo un tipo de datos, que su tipo no varía en tiempo de ejecución y que su tipo se define en el momento de definición de la variable.

Así pues, `auto` deduce el tipo de la variable en base a su inicializador:

```
auto x = 42;      // x es int
auto y = 42u;     // y es unsigned int
auto z = 42f;     // z es float
auto t = .42;     // t es double
auto u = 42l;     // u es long
auto v = 42ull;   // u es unsigned long long
auto w = new int; // w es int *
auto e = 'a' + 0b0001 + .0f; // e es float porque la expresión completa es float
```

Por lo tanto, dado que el retorno de [`chrono::duration_cast` [image]](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/duration/duration_cast) es una duración, `auto` deduce [`std::chrono::duration` [image]](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/duration) y a un `float` no se le puede sumar ese dato, obtienes el error.

A parte de la solución aportada por [Neoniet](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/216219/2742), podrías definir el operador que te falta:

```
template <typename T>
float &operator +=(float &f, const std::chrono::duration<T> &d)
{
    return (f += d.count());
}
```

Comment: Pues la verdad... ésta me parece una mejor respuesta ;-)

Answer (score 6):

Yo haría algo así.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>

using namespace std::chrono;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
        int i=0;
        std::chrono::duration<float,std::milli> duracion,tiempo_ejecucion;

        while(i<10)
        {
                auto inicio = high_resolution_clock::now();
                // lo que sea que haya que medir
                auto fin = high_resolution_clock::now();
                duracion = (fin - inicio);

                tiempo_ejecucion += duracion; 
                i++;
        }

        std::cout << "tiempo de ejecucion" << (tiempo_ejecucion.count()/10) << std::endl;
        return 0;
}
```

Que yo sepa [auto](https://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/auto) implica que el tipo de variable es el de su inicializador... pero nada más.

Comment: Te confirmo que auto deduce el tipo de datos del inicializador y nada más.